# uploading, storing and browsing millions of tiny files - best practices

Tags: files, filesystems, shared-folders

I am dealing with an application that generates thousands of tiny files a day. These files shoud then be uploaded to a NAS and be browsed from a network share from Windows machines.

While the process technically works, it is very, very slow both to upload and browse the files - from the Windows machines, it is too slow to browse without frustration.

These files are very small in size - millions of them clock in well below 100MB.

I have thought of several possible options to remedy this:

- Compress the files with `gz` (attempted, did not help significantly)
- Gather the files to several `.tar` archives based on age (which will split them to around 10 archives)
- Upload them to a different NAS utilizing ZFS (current one does not).

The servers running this application runs on XFS, and I cannot reformat it to use anything else.

While I'm not sure any of these will help, I was curious to what would be the best way to handle this situation, in your experience.

What are some best practices when dealing with many small files?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE: thank you all for your suggestions. I grouped the files into tar archives and replaced the share with NFS, things are much smoother now.
Thank you!

Comment: I find the CIFS protocol is my bottleneck.  If you can use something other than Samba/CIFS you'll probably see improvements.  That could be NFS or sshfs (but affects your client configuration).  I don't think switching to ZFS will help as it's not the bottleneck.   I also don't think compression will help because the bottleneck is the directory listing, not the files themselves.  @Vladimir Dobias's answer is good and will mitigate the problem as it will reduce the size of each directory listing.

Comment: Given that the average file size must be well under 100 bytes, but the block size is (probably) 4096, your disk space is only utilised with about 2% efficiency. This is begging for a redesign using a database solution, even if that culls the original files in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not store all files in one directory. Regardless of which filesystem you use browsing will be very very slow. Create subdirectories or possibly two or three levels of subdirectories. It depends on what makes sense for your particular case.

Comment: Absolutely this. Typically I split filenames from right to left, because empirically the right-hand side offers more variation (and therefore a better spread) then the left. Exclude any standard file extension/suffix when applying this approach. Example `helloworld.jpg` might be stored as `orld/llow/helloworld.jpg`